# (R-ggsurvplot) Why not 100% survival at x=0 and why is there a survival graph before x=0?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am doing survival analysis by R.
However, the graph showed survival graph before the "x=0".
Is it an error?

[image]

Comment: survival curves will plot with negative times, that's up to you to fix

Comment: If you could share some code we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Please provide a piece of data. This is a good question!